# How do I read an element of an dynamically allocated matrix in which every element is a structure

Tags: c, matrix

So, I have  a structure  with 3 different pointer variables.What i need to do is to intiate a dynamically allocated matrix in which every element is the type of that structure. I think that I have correctly allocated the memory for the matrix and for the members of the structure, but now I don`t know how to read every element of that matrix. I am a beginner so forgive my coding style or any other mistakes. My question is how do I read an element of an dynamically allocated matrix in which every element is a structure?

(I know that in the structure I could have written   "char *x,*y,*z;"   but I can see it better this way)

```
typedef struct{char *type_present;
               char *destination;
               char *direction;
               int no_available_presents;
           }MAP;

int main(){
    int max_line,max_col,i,j;
    MAP **map;

    //Allocating memory for the matrix

    map=malloc(max_line * sizeof(MAP) );
        for(i = 0; i < max_line; i++){
            map[i]=calloc(col,sizeof(MAP));
        }

    //Allocating memory for the members of the structure

    (*map)->destination=(char)malloc(1 * sizeof(char));
    (*map)->direction=(char)malloc(1 * sizeof(char));
    (*map)->type_present=(char)malloc(1 * sizeof(char));


    /*Here is my problem, I don`t know if this is good, the warning is that 
    the format '%s' expects 'char' and the argument is '**char'.I know 
    that, I don`t know how to fix it but I think the real problem is that 
    my code here is simply incorrect.*/

    for(i = 0; i < max_line; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < max_col; j++){
            scanf("%s\n", &(*map)->destination);
            scanf("%s\n", &(*map)->direction);
            scanf("%s\n", &(*map)->type_present);
            scanf("%d\n", &(*map)->no_available_presents);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just tell me one thing - each element of the matrix is an instance of struct `MAP`?

Comment: `col` is not initialized.

Comment: Oh yeah, I simply forgot to intiate 'col'  when i was copyng my code.Yes every element of the matrix is an instance of the struct MAP.

Comment: @coderredoc  I am sorry, I just made my account, I don`t know all the stuff, thanks, I`ll keep it in mind for the future

Comment: @MateiCristianNicusor.: Good :) All the best

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is this line:

```
map=malloc(max_line * sizeof(MAP) );
```

Here you want an array of pointers so the line shall be:

```
map=malloc(max_line * sizeof(MAP*) );
                                ^
                               notice
```

The next problem is this part

```
//Allocating memory for the members of the structure

(*map)->destination=(char)malloc(1 * sizeof(char));
(*map)->direction=(char)malloc(1 * sizeof(char));
(*map)->type_present=(char)malloc(1 * sizeof(char));
```

It is wrong for several reason. First of all you only initialize a single MAP instead of doing it for all. Further it doesn't make sense to allocate a single char when you want to store a string.

So the initialization shall rather be:

```
//Allocating memory for the members of the structure
for(i = 0; i < max_line; i++){
{
    for(j = 0; j < max_col; j++){
    {
        map[i][j].destination = malloc(MAX_STRING_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
        map[i][j].direction = malloc(MAX_STRING_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
        map[i][j].type_present = malloc(MAX_STRING_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
    }
}
```

As you can see above, you access the individual structs simply by `map[i][j]` so your scanf can be

```
scanf("%s\n", map[i][j].destination);
```

BTW: `scanf("%s....` is bad as the user can overflow your buffer. Consider using `fgets` or at least do `scanf("%42s...` where 42 is the buffer length (minus 1).

Comment: Can't agree with your fixed string solution. It wastes a lot of memory. He can do that while reading. It is also doubtfull he wants to have a two dimensional array.

Comment: I see now, i thought that 1 stance for a whole entire string.I tried at first using fgets but i simply couldn`t make it work, thank you for all the tips.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie - True.... but I don't think OPs focus is on that kind of optimization.

Comment: @4386427 I tried your version , exactly as you said and now it says format '%s' expects 'char *' but the argument has 'char **'.I really don`t know how to fix this.Can you please help me?

Comment: @MateiCristianNicusor - on which line?

Comment: @4386427 I tried reading my structure members like you said with scanf in 2 fors , one with i, and one with j

Comment: Did you do `&map[i][j].destination` ? If so remove the `&`.

Comment: @4386427 it is with '&', i tried what you said, i mean removing it and then when i compile it , i have no errors or warnings but when i run it it says seg fault.....

Comment: Did you remember to initialize `max_line` and `max_col`

Comment: @4386427 yes , i am reading them with a scanf in the beginning of int main

Comment: @MateiCristianNicusor and `MAX_STRING_LENGTH` also?

Comment: @4386427 i understand that those max_string_lenght are for everyone of the members so i figure it out and change max_string_lenght with 50 for everyone

Comment: @4386427 i really don`t know why it did that but now it works. All i changed was instead of every 50 * sizeof(char) i said MAX_STRING_LENGTH and define it before int main and where calloc is , instead of col i changed it to max_col. Anyway thank you so very much